# Unwarp tags and put comma in between expect single Tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

As per out requirement we need to wrap the content of para separated by comma.We are able to do that.
But should not consider thiru Tag for comma it has to be appended to previous tag or next tag.
In case of only para is before and after then it should be appended with both.

See below example:

Input4:

```
<Para>Apple1
    <Thiru>Mango1<Ref>Grape1</Ref><Ref>Grape2</Ref><Ref>Grape3</Ref>Mango2</Thiru>Apple2
</Para>
```

output4:

```
<Para>Apple1Mango1,Grape1,Grape2,Grape3Mango2,Apple2</Para>
```

Current xsl:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$Cells/Para/@*" />
<xsl:for-each select="$Cells/Para/node()[self::text() or self::Ref or self::Thiru][normalize-space(.)!='']">
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" />
<xsl:if test="position()!=last()" >
<xsl:value-of select="','" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

By using current xsl we are getting , for all the element.My Requirement is we should not considered Tag Thiru.

Please verify the sample Input and output.

Comment: Test case 4 seems to contradict test case 1. In test case 1, a comma is *not* output between the content of `Thiru` and the last string, but in test case 4, it *is* output. Please resolve this contradiction.

Comment: Hi @SeanB.Durkin, Thansk for your response. Actullly that is the rqquirement. If para has only thiru the first output is expected. If Ref is present in front and back of Thieu then value should be applied to the ref and comma should be applied. ie) We sould not consider Thiru at all.

Comment: Where did `1234` come from in test case 3? It is not even in the input.

Comment: Could you carefully review your test cases please. They do not match your words.

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin thanks for pointing it out. I have made corrections to the input3 and output3

Comment: Shouldn't test case 1 output be ABC1234,CDEF  ?

Comment: My test case is correct.Incase if you can do that only we are fine with that.We will try to find alternate solution for that scenario.

Comment: Can you explain why there is a comma after the thiru element in case 3, before CDEF text node, but there is *no* comma after the thiru element in case 1. It seems like a contradiction.

Comment: Main reason is if the Tag Thiru comes we should not append comma but if tag Ref comes we should append comma. So we came up with this case. If Thiru comes between two diffrent ref then thiru should be associated with only one ref since we need to diffrenciate between ref and ref or ref and para.I hope this clarify your question.Please let me know if you need more info.Thanks for your help

Comment: No. Sorry. Completly confused.

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. Just ignore all the input and output consider only input and output 4.

Comment: Like @SeanB.Durkin, I'm also confused. Please [edit] the question in such a way that the things that need to be considered are in it, and the things that need not be considered are not.

Comment: I have update the question.I am ok with only one scenario.Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your current input and expected output, I am assuming the following rules

1. Don't place a comma before the first text element
2. Don't place a comma before a text element whose parent is `Thiru`

In this case, try this stylesheet: (Note I have reversed the logic, so it is actually checking whether a comma should be placed, rather than not to be placed)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//text()">
                <xsl:if test="position() > 1 and not(parent::Thiru)">,</xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following input:

```
<Para>Apple1
    <Thiru>Mango1<Ref>Grape1</Ref><Ref>Grape2</Ref><Ref>Grape3</Ref>Mango2</Thiru>Apple2
</Para>
```

The following is output

```
<Para>Apple1Mango1,Grape1,Grape2,Grape3Mango2,Apple2</Para>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.It works fine. I will put separate post and its answer for my full requirement.